# In-App Purchase "product not found" for a product I just created

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, in-app-purchase, skproduct

I have a game and I want to add in-app purchases.

I have implemented code into my project. I have set up everything like it should in iTunes Connect. I got no errors (only some deprecation issues). But the app won't work.

I get this line in the log:

> Product not found: com.doubleoapps.nonconsumable3

and the product that isn't found is the one product I just made in iTunes Connect.

Here is the code logging my error:

```
#pragma mark SKProductsRequestDelegate

-(void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{
    NSArray *products = response.products;
    if (products.count != 0)
    {
        _product = products[0];
        _buyButton.enabled = YES;
        _productTitle.text = _product.localizedTitle;
        _productDescription.text = _product.localizedDescription;
    } else {
        _productTitle.text = @"Product not found";
    }
    products = response.invalidProductIdentifiers;
    for (SKProduct *product in products)
    {
        NSLog(@"Product not found: %@", product); }
}
```

Is anyone able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: What is the status of the product in iTunesConnect?

Comment: "waiting for screenshot" same status on both apps.

Answer (score 0):

Have you figured it out? I'm in the same boat trying to figure it all out. Some stuff I read said you need to upload your binary and reject. After trying that and waiting a few hours, my SKProductsRequest still came back empty and my product was in the invalid products identifier list.

I just read in Apple's docs that you are not supposed to upload/reject binaries or else it won't work:

> Testing In-App Purchase will fail if you or App Review reject your most recent binary in iTunes Connect. The workaround in this case is to upload a binary without In-App Purchase features that can get approved by App Review. Once the binary is approved, resume testing the binary with In-App Purchase features.

I just uploaded a version with some minor bug fixes and no IAP code. Will have to wait for that to complete and then try again.

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons why you would get the response you are getting.  Check out TN2259 especially FAQ #6.

Also, be sure to delete old builds of the App and log out of the App Store then reinstall from Xcode and log back in only when asked.  This will assure that your App appears to be signed by a developer profile and that you are actually being directed to the sandbox environment and not the production environment.

And finally, test users can become broken especially if they log into the production environment (see above).  Creating a new one is often helpful.